# If statement expecting ]

Tags: objective-c, syntax, if-statement

```
if (menuPlayed == TRUE && [sender tag == 0]) {
    NSLog(@"You're pressing the right button at the right time");
}
```

Any idea why this is throwing up a "Expected "]
"" error? I have absolutely no idea what's wrong with those comparisons :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
if ((menuPlayed == TRUE) && ([sender tag] == 0))
```

And you'll probably have to typecast sender, something like

```
if ((menuPlayed == TRUE) && ([(UIButton *)sender tag] == 0))
```

Ofcourse you shouldn't just use (UIButton *) for typecast.
Use the correct class of your sender object or use one
of it's ancestor classes. I believe 'tag' is added to
UIView in this object hierarchy.

Comment: Cleanliness, I prefer this style too.

Comment: Just for readability. Compiled code will be the same but when if clauses get more complex one could miss something if not using extra parentheses

Comment: I guess it's a matter of personal preference - my concern though was that in the context of this particular question and answer the addition of the parentheses might seem to imply that these are actually *required* in order to address the problem.

Comment: True. But for this particural question he'll have to typecast sender - id has not tag property.

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
if (menuPlayed == TRUE && [sender tag == 0])
```

to:

```
if (menuPlayed == TRUE && [sender tag] == 0)
```

Also note that you should never write expressions such as `menuPlayed == TRUE` - always write this as just `menuPlayed`, i.e. in this particular case:

```
if (menuPlayed && [sender tag] == 0)
```

And as mentioned in @rokjarc's answer, you might want to add some parentheses for clarity, although these are not actually required:

```
if (menuPlayed && ([sender tag] == 0))
```